# Magento 2.3.3 on Centos 7 with Nginx using composer - Website not working?

Tags: installation, magento2.3.3, nginx, php-7.2, centos

Following tutorial : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html

After download magento by using,

```
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.3.3 magento
```

Folder path : **`var/ww/html/magento`**

I am using centos 7 - Nginx how to run following last 2 commands,

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chown -R :www-data . # Ubuntu
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Finally my installation command,

```
bin/magento setup:install –base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento –db-host=localhost –db-name=magento –db-user=root –db-password=P@ssword123 –admin-firstname=mage –admin-lastname=mage --admin-email=mage@gmail.com –admin-user=mage –admin-password=mage@123 –language=en_US –currency=INR –timezone=Asia/Kolkata –use-rewrites=1
```

How to setup magento.conf in etc/nginx/config.d/ magento.conf?

my magento.conf :

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
     server  127.0.0.1:9000;
 }

 server {

     listen 8085;
     server_name 192.168.1.65:8085;
     set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento;
     include /var/www/html/magento/nginx.conf.sample;
 }
```

In url section if i type **192.168.1.65:8085** getting blank page.

**FYI** - After install magento 2.3.3 not created env.php file under \app\etc.

Comment: For Moderator : I hope my explanation good, if not understandable pls let me know i will explain more?

Answer (score 0):

you need to know your php-fpm user:

```
egrep '^user|^group' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

then you can use proper `chown` command

installation command must look like this:

```
bin/magento setup:install \
-–base-url="http://192.168.1.65:8085/" \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=root \
--db-password="P@ssword123" \
--admin-firstname=mage \
--admin-lastname=mage \
--admin-email="mage@gmail.com" \
--admin-user=mage \
--admin-password="mage@123" \
--language=en_US \
--currency=INR \
--timezone="Asia/Kolkata" \
--use-rewrites=1
```

note `--base-url` value: **`http://192.168.1.65:8085/`**

it is your server name.

if you have blank page without any DNS or connection errors, then you need to check magento error log.

Comment: How to use Multi-Website localhost URL into Nginx configuration, main url: 192.168.1.65:8087/ (working good) Multi-Website url : 192.168.1.65:8087/grocery/